# Getting files from URL working first, but not later on the script

Tags: php, html, dom, file-get-contents

Im having a dumb problem, im trying to make a script that would copy linked css stylesheets from a website.

Everything works as expected but when trying to extract css files with root paths, like `/cached.php?t=1540425603&f=/styles/theme-base.css`, at the start of the script the i have an echo command to test out that the link should work

```
echo file_get_contents('http://php.net/cached.php?t=1539765004&f=/styles/theme-base.css');
```

and it echos the css file correctly, BUUT later in the script trying to do the same thing it just returns the HTML of `php.net` instead of the css, like it did at teh start of the script.

The stylesheet link after the `format_url() function`, shows the correct css if you paste it in the browser.
https://php.net/cached.php?t=1540425603&f=/styles/theme-base.css

So after loading the DOM with SimpleHTMLDom, I loop through `link` elements, format the URLs from relative to absolute with `format_url()` and then save the data from the href to a file on the server with `save_file()`

```
foreach($html->find('link') as $element) {
       $name = save_file(format_url($element->href, $og_url), $fol);
       $element->href = $name;

    }
```

The basename of the file is being returned so the href in the html file can be changed to that.

This just boggles my mind, see the url is echoed before `file_get_contents()` and the link that gives, works perfectly in the browser and at the start of the script, but not here.

```
function save_file($url, $fol) {
        echo $url.'<br>';

        $file = file_get_contents($url);

        $name = pathinfo($url);
        $fp = $fol.'/'.$name['basename'];
        file_put_contents($fp, $file);
        return $name['basename'];

    }
```

The format_url function formats all kinds of URLs but here the stylesheets are the types that start from the root folder.

```
function format_url($url, $page) {
        $x = parse_url($page);
        $urlX = explode('/', $url);
        $name = end($urlX);

        if(strpos($url, 'http') === 0) {

        } else if(strpos($url, '//') === 0) {

            $url = 'https:'.$url;

        } else {
        // RELATIVE URL 

            // ROOT FOLDER
            if(strpos($url, '/') === 0) {
                $url = $x['scheme'].'://'.$x['host'].$url;


            } else {
                $url = rel2abs($url, $page);

            }
        }
        return $url;
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug whats ```$url``` inside function ```save_file``` ? (Try to ```var_dump``` it

Comment: cached files dont last for ever, maybe it expired.

Comment: yea i have it echo every url befori it gets its content and the urls are fine

Comment: `http://php.net/cached.php?t=1539765004&f=/styles/theme-base.css` does not return any content - it issues a _redirect_ to `http://php.net/cached.php?t=1539765004&f=/styles/theme-base.css` - but `file_get_contents` does not follow redirects automatically on its own.